# Would a modern compiler optimize "if false" paths?

Tags: function, gcc, compiler-construction

Would a modern compiler (GCC) be smart enough to optimize this no-op function out?
I know that they can optimize no-op's out but I'm wondering how well they can determine if a function call is actually a no-op.

```
void someFunction(){
    if false{
        doFunction()
    }
}
```

Comment: To actually see the behavior you can run the code in gdb and stepping through the function. While in gdb before you  start stepping into the code press Ctrl + x and then 2 to see your code and corresponding assembly. When you will step over the code that has been optimized out gdb will print a message value optimized.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for a start, it wouldn't compile that at all since you're missing parentheses around your condition :-)

But, with that fixed, I think you'll find that the `if` statement itself (and it's body) can be optimised out of existence. The `someFunction()` function will almost certainly remain since you may call it from somewhere, and that somewhere may be from a totally different translation unit (source file).

If it was *static* and the compiler could deduce that the function was not used, it would be possible to remove the whole function. That works because, being static, it would not be callable from elsewhere.

However, you'd have to be careful. Calling functions is not the only way to use them, there's other possibilities such as taking the address of them and using *that,* such as with callbacks.

Comment: I was just writing some quick pseudocode, not supposed to be a real function

Answer (score 0):

Modern compilers perform static analysis and remove unreachable code.